# Align button group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I use bootstrap 3.
I have an bootstrap-table, on top of it, i have a button group i would like to align to the right of the table. Actually is a the left

http://jsfiddle.net/65uckof7/

```
  <div id="toolbar" class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">
        Actions
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li>
              <a href="#">Anuler</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Sauvegarder</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Payez</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Comptant</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Débit</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Chèque</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the action button to be on the right?

If that's the case from your fiddle I just had to add the following CSS rule:

```
.fixed-table-toolbar .pull-left {
    float: right !important;
}
```

You need this because from the CSS on the fiddle the class .pull-left (the one which contains the buttons) is set to: `float: left !important;` so you just need to set it to right with the CSS I've provided

Comment: that will affect all my others... is it possible to do it only for this one?

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 2.3, see: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#misc-> Helper Classes -> .pull-right

For Bootstrap 3, see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes -> Helper classes

So, insert 'pull-right' into the class string and let bootstrap arrange the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Juste add .pull-right to .fixed-table-toolbar

Answer (score 0):

use `pull-right` class instead of `pull-left`